# Using CGAL to partition a non-simple polygon

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Suppose that I have a non-simple polygon, 
how CGAL can help me to partition it into a set of simple polygons?

For example, give a polygon represented by a sequence of 2D points:

```
(1, 1) (1, -1) (-1, 1) (-1, -1)
```

I wish to acquire two polygons;

```
(1, 1) (1, -1) (0, 0)
```

and

```
(0, 0) (-1, 1) (-1, -1)
```

Is it doable for CGAL?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems abandoned... Anyway, I'm adding a simple code to answer it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>

using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using Traits = CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel>;
using Arrangement = CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits>;
using Point = Traits::Point_2;
using Segment = Traits::Segment_2;
using Polygon = CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>;

int main()
{
  // ------ create a segment chain
  Point const p1(1, 1), p2(1, -1), p3(-1, 1), p4(-1, -1);
  std::vector<Segment> const cv = {{p1, p2}, {p2, p3}, {p3, p4}, {p4, p1}};
  // ------ create the arrangement
  Arrangement arr;
  CGAL::insert(arr, cv.cbegin(), cv.cend());
  // ------ iterate the arrangement bounded faces and create simple polygons
  std::vector<Polygon> polygons;
  for (auto fit = arr.faces_begin(); fit != arr.faces_end(); ++fit)
  {
    if (not fit->is_unbounded())
    {
      Polygon poly;
      auto const heitBeg = fit->outer_ccb();
      auto heit = heitBeg;
      do {poly.push_back(heit->source()->point());} while (++heit != heitBeg);
      polygons.push_back(poly);
    }
  }
  // ------ print simple polygons
  auto polyN = 1;
  for (auto const& p: polygons)
  {
    std::cout << "Polygon #" << polyN++ << ": ";
    for (auto const& v: p.vertices()) std::cout << '(' << v << ") ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The function `CGAL::insert` **automatically** computes the intersection point (0,0). The output is:

```
Polygon #1: (-0 -0) (-1 1) (-1 -1)
Polygon #2: (1 1) (-0 -0) (1 -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your required two polygons do not make up the original hull. If you just want to break your original set into triangles using (0,0) as one of the vertices you can do this:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_mesh_vertex_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2.h>
#include <vector>    

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel     K;
typedef K::Point_2                                              Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_vertex_base_2<K>                    Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<K>                      Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb>            Tds;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds>      CDT;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle                                      Vertex_handle;
typedef CDT::Face_iterator                                      Face_iterator;    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create a vector of the points
    //
    std::vector<Point_2> points2D ;
    points2D.push_back(Point_2(  1,  1));
    points2D.push_back(Point_2(  1, -1));
    points2D.push_back(Point_2( -1,  1));
    points2D.push_back(Point_2( -1, -1));
    points2D.push_back(Point_2( 0, 0));

    size_t numTestPoints = points2D.size();

    // Create a constrained delaunay triangulation and add the points
    //
    CDT cdt;
    std::vector<Vertex_handle> vhs;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<numTestPoints; ++i){
        vhs.push_back(cdt.insert(points2D[i]));
    }

    int i=0;
    for (Face_iterator fit = cdt.faces_begin()  ; fit != cdt.faces_end(); ++fit) {
        printf("Face %d is (%f,%f) -- (%f,%f) -- (%f,%f) \n",i++,
               fit->vertex(0)->point().x(),fit->vertex(0)->point().y(),
               fit->vertex(1)->point().x(),fit->vertex(1)->point().y(),
               fit->vertex(2)->point().x(),fit->vertex(2)->point().y() );

    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Which should give you output like this:

```
Face 0 is (0.000000,0.000000) -- (1.000000,-1.000000) -- (1.000000,1.000000) 
Face 1 is (0.000000,0.000000) -- (1.000000,1.000000) -- (-1.000000,1.000000) 
Face 2 is (-1.000000,-1.000000) -- (0.000000,0.000000) -- (-1.000000,1.000000) 
Face 3 is (-1.000000,-1.000000) -- (1.000000,-1.000000) -- (0.000000,0.000000)
```